# Dont do animations if divs are already animating

Tags: jquery

I have some animations and fades on mouseover and mouseout but I don't want them to trigger if the divs are already being animated.

This is what I tried but it isn't working (if I mouseover and mouseout it goes crazy).

```
$('.hover-div').mouseover(function() {

        if ( ( $('.carousel-bg').not(':animated') ) && ( $('div.carousel-holder div.text').not(':animated') ) ) {

            $('div.hidden').fadeIn(1000);

            $('.carousel-bg').animate({
                'top': 0,
                'height': 360
            }, 200);

            $('div.carousel-holder div.text').animate({
                'top': 75
            });

        }

    });

    $('.hover-div').mouseout(function() {

        if ( ($('.carousel-bg').not(':animated')) && ($('div.carousel-holder div.text').not(':animated')) ) {

            $('div.hidden').hide();

            $('.carousel-bg').animate({
                'top': 112,
                'height': 130
            }, 200);

            $('div.carousel-holder div.text').animate({
                'top': 125
            });

        }
```

Comment: have you tried out my solution.?

Comment: Yes. It is what I am looking for. I will accept it as soon as it permits me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `is()` instead of `not()`

```
if(!$('.carousel-bg').is(':animated') ....
```

Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to know more about `.is()`

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario we use `stop()`.

```
$('.carousel-bg').stop();
```

Comment: yeah use .stop() which cancels the current animation if another one is fired before the current one has finished

Comment: Thanks, but the other answer is more what I am looking for because I have some fades inside as well which I don't want happening.